# List View Dropdown missing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have placed a content editor web part on the list view page. The List, Item tabs and the View name with drop down went missing. I was able to get the List and Item tabs up with the below script but there are going away if i click on the page.

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2');
    if(elem != null) {
        var dummyevent = new Array();
        dummyevent["target"] = elem;
        dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
        WpClick(dummyevent);
      }
  }, 2000);
```

Any kind of help leading to resolve the issue would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit the list view page, it no longer defaults to putting focus on the list view web part and so you're having to either 1) click on the list view web part when the page loads or 2) use javascript to assign focus after page load or 3) remove the extra web part, restoring it to default.

Comment: Graham, Thanks for the reply. Setting the focus worked for theList and Item Tabs. But the view name with the drop down to navigate to other views is still missing. Any suggestions on that would be helpful.

Comment: Go into the web part configuration and go to the Miscellaneous section and deselect 'Disable View Selector Menu' You can also turn on/off the search box that way.

Comment: Graham, the  'Disable View Selector Menu' is already deselected. I tried selecting it and deselecting again. It did not work.